# SwiftUI CollectionView wrapper cannot apply snapshot from updateUIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I have implemented such UICollectionView wrapper

```
struct CollectionView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let layout: UICollectionViewLayout
    let sections: [Section]
    let items: [Section: [Item]]

    // MARK: - Actions
    let content: (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView

    init(layout: UICollectionViewLayout,
         sections: [Section],
         items: [Section: [Item]],
         @ViewBuilder content:  @escaping (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView) {
        self.layout = layout

        self.sections = sections
        self.items = items

        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CollectionViewController {

        let controller = CollectionViewController()
        controller.layout = layout
        controller.content = content
        controller.snapshot = snapshotForCurrentState()

        controller.collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator

        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: CollectionViewController, context: Context) {

        controller.snapshot = snapshotForCurrentState()
        controller.reloadDataSource()
    }


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

And here is code of CollectionViewController

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    var layout: UICollectionViewLayout! = nil
    var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>! = nil
    var content: ((_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView)! = nil

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "diffQueue")

    lazy var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item> = {
        let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: cellProvider)
        return dataSource
    }()

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .red //.clear
        return collectionView
    }()

    var isLoaded: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureCollectionView()

        // load initial data
        reloadDataSource()

        isLoaded = true
    }
}

extension CollectionViewController {

    func reloadDataSource(animating: Bool = false) {

        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animating) {
            print("applying snapshot completed!")
        }
    }
}

extension CollectionViewController {

    private func configureCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier)

        collectionView.delegate = self

        print("configured collection view")
    }

    private func cellProvider(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? {

        print("providing cell for \(indexPath)...")
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView> else {
            fatalError("Could not load cell")
        }

        //cell.host(AnyView(Text(item.title)))
        cell.host(content(indexPath, item))

        return cell
    }
}
```

It works but I can only load data source in viewDidLoad calling `reloadDatasource()` if this method is then called again from updateUIViewController in UIViewControllerRepresentable then collection view is left empty.

Here is full repository of this sample CollectionView wrapper 
https://github.com/michzio/SwifUICollectionView

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that I am getting this error

```
2020-05-02 07:18:20.891685+0200 SwiftUICollectionView[39727:58991470] [CollectionView] Layout attributes <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbd6f30b270> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xd64d621a2e1d9027> {length = 2, path = 0 - 37}); frame = (187.667 792; 187.667 44);  were received from the layout <UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x7fbd6df04920> but are not valid for the data source counts. Attributes will be ignored.
```

I've also noticed that if I change in updateUIViewController

```
controller.reloadDataSource(animating: false)
```

to

```
controller.reloadDataSource(animating: true)
```

cell are displayed. But consecutive refresh enforced on tap gesture hangs UI ( I think maybe there is too many items and calculating animation has problems, but no even if I decreased number of items to 1000 it freezes.)

UPDATE 2

Now when animating: true in reloadDataSource() (from updateUIViewController) I can get crashes but there is no information only EXC_BAD_ARITHM

if I remove initial data loading in CollectionViewController.viewDidLoad() then only updateUIViewController is called and here another wierd exception happens

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3920.26.113/UICollectionView.m:5971
>   2020-05-02 07:33:02.037804+0200 SwiftUICollectionView[40091:59004149]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ItemCell - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39f0e **exceptionPreprocess + 350  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff50ad79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff23e39c88 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88    3
>
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff258a3cd2
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191     4
>
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4838b36e
>   -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 2426   5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4838b53d -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 88    6
>
>   SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b5fcb3
>   $s21SwiftUICollectionView010CollectionC10ControllerC12cellProvider33_7499D878310ABE7B5F37FEF32561A438LL010collectionC09indexPath4itemSo0bC4CellCSgSo0bC0C_10Foundation05IndexP0VAA4ItemCtF
>   + 867     7   SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b62ad0 $s21SwiftUICollectionView010CollectionC10ControllerC12cellProvider33_7499D878310ABE7B5F37FEF32561A438LL010collectionC09indexPath4itemSo0bC4CellCSgSo0bC0C_10Foundation05IndexP0VAA4ItemCtFTA
>   + 16  8   SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b5ffaf $sSo16UICollectionViewC10Foundation9IndexPathV05SwiftaB04ItemCSo0aB4CellCSgIeggngo_AbehKIeggnno_TR
>   + 15  9   libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff5170a8ce $s5UIKit29UITableViewDiffableDataSourceC05tableC012cellProviderACyxq_GSo0bC0C_So0bC4CellCSgAH_10Foundation9IndexPathVq_tctcfcAkH_ANyptcfU_ + 126     10  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff5170a998 $sSo11UITableViewC10Foundation9IndexPathVypSo0aB4CellCSgIeggnno_ABSo07NSIndexE0CyXlAHIeyByyya_TR
>   + 168     11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48342a89 -[__UIDiffableDataSource collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 165   12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483432d5
>   -[__UIDiffableDataSource _cellForItemAtIndexPath:collectionView:] + 50    13  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff5170b036
>   $s5UIKit34UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceC010collectionC0_13cellForItemAtSo0bC4CellCSo0bC0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTm
>   + 70  14  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff5170b110 $s5UIKit34UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceC010collectionC0_13cellForItemAtSo0bC4CellCSo0bC0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFToTm
>   + 128     15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483759d5 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:]
>   + 416     16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4837582f -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
>   + 31  17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48395e4e __51-[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate]_block_invoke.1814 + 661  18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483929e4
>   -[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate] + 3213    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48399cde
>   __71-[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:animator:]_block_invoke.1887 + 118   20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490bb8a8 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 84   21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48398b24 -[UICollectionView
>   _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 4003   22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48391689
>   -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:]
>   + 16761   23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839b0e6 -[UICollectionView _endUpdatesWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 71   24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839b445 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:]
>   + 462     25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839b254 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:]
>   + 90  26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839b1d7 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:] + 74    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4839b12c
>   -[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 53  28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff483aa9ef
>   -[UICollectionView _performDiffableUpdate:] + 44  29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4834906e -[_UIDiffableDataSourceViewUpdater
>   _performUpdateWithCollectionViewUpdateItems:dataSourceSnapshotter:updateHandler:completion:]
>   + 467     30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4834213a -[__UIDiffableDataSource _commitNewDataSource:withViewUpdates:completion:] + 246     31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4833cb22 __66-[__UIDiffableDataSource
>   applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 190  32 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4833cdb1
>   __66-[__UIDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:]_block_invoke.180 + 107     33 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108e01e8e
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108e10ae2 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete +
>   132   35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4833c62b
>   -[__UIDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:] + 952  36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4833d63d
>   -[__UIDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:animatingDifferences:completion:] + 71
>     37  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff5170aaf4
>   $s5UIKit34UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceC5apply_20animatingDifferences10completionyAA010NSDiffableeF8SnapshotVyxq_G_SbyycSgtFTm
>   + 212     38  SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b620b9 $s21SwiftUICollectionView010CollectionC10ControllerC16reloadDataSource8snapshot9animatingy5UIKit010NSDiffablegH8SnapshotVyAA7SectionOAA4ItemCG_SbtF
>   + 985     39  SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b5682f $s21SwiftUICollectionView010CollectionC0V22updateUIViewController_7contextyAA0dcG0C_0A2UI0fG20RepresentableContextVyACGtF
>   + 335     40  SwiftUICollectionView               0x0000000108b56a2b $s21SwiftUICollectionView010CollectionC0V0A2UI29UIViewControllerRepresentableAadEP06updatefG0_7contexty0fG4TypeQz_AD0fgH7ContextVyxGtFTW
>   + 59  41  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c59a1b2 $s7SwiftUI42PlatformViewControllerRepresentableAdaptorV06updateD8Provider_7contexty06UIViewE4TypeQz_AA0cdF7ContextVyACyxGGtF
>   + 290     42  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c670439 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_
>   + 217     43  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c7f5e20 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE21performExternalUpdateyyyyXEF + 192
>     44  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c66f810
>   $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tFyyXEfU_7performL_4workyyyXE_tAA0cD13RepresentableRzlF
>   + 224     45  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c66e6b6 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tFyyXEfU_
>   + 2454    46  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c6674ae $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tF
>   + 590     47  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c670940 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLVyxG14AttributeGraph07UntypedM0AafGP7_update_5graph9attributeySv_So10AGGraphRefaSo11AGAttributeatFZTW
>   + 32  48  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2fc46309 $sTA + 25    49  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2fc2ed45 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 455     50  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2fc2f253 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeEjb + 373  51 
>   AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2fc33d5b
>   _ZN2AG8Subgraph6updateEj + 729    52  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c51d690
>   $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC14runTransaction33_D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98BLL2inySo10AGGraphRefa_tF
>   + 224     53  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c51da67 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateOutputs2atyAA4TimeV_tFSb5prefs_Sb9idealSizeAC0F0V7outputstSo10AGGraphRefaXEfU_
>   + 103     54  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c51d74d $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateOutputs2atyAA4TimeV_tF + 125    55  SwiftUI
>   0x00007fff2c80146b
>   $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_
>   + 811     56  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c8008c3 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_
>   + 547     57  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c7f6415 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtF
>   + 373     58  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c956102 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyF + 226     59  SwiftUI
>
>   0x00007fff2c956125 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyFTo +
>   21    60  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490c9848
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478     61  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4ae3f0 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 255    62  QuartzCore
>
>   0x00007fff2b4b457b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   523   63  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4bfc12
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80    64  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b408c84
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324  65  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b43c65f
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 649    66  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48bdfc2b __34-[UIApplication
>   _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81    67  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9dcdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12     68 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9d3d3
>   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195     69  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d981c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 995     70  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff23d97ac4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404     71  GraphicsServices
>   0x00007fff38b2fc1a GSEventRunModal + 139  72  UIKitCore
>   0x00007fff48bc7f80 UIApplicationMain + 1605   73  SwiftUICollectionView
>   0x0000000108b548fb main + 75  74  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff519521fd start + 1 )

I forgot to say that this exceptions start to happen when I replaced CompositionalLayout wit simple UICollectionFlowLayout!

Answer (score 0):

As I see you don't apply a new snapshot in updateUIViewController method. It should be something like this

```
func updateUIViewController(_ controller: CollectionViewController, context: Context) {

    controller.snapshot = snapshotForCurrentState()
    controller.reloadDataSource()
}
```

Comment: I have this code 
 func updateUIViewController(_ controller: CollectionViewController, context: Context) {

        controller.snapshot = snapshotForCurrentState()
        controller.reloadDataSource()
    }

Above I just pasted mistyped code. But with this reloadDataSource() it does not work